# Laravel - forget previous urls in session

Tags: php, laravel, session, authentication, logout

Situation:

In our system, logging user out from Admin only logged them out of admin section and we wanted them logged out of application (we are using the encore admin package for laravel). I created a new logout class which overrides the default admin logout, and runs the standard laravel logout as well. This successfully logged the user out of the system and returned them to login screen.

Problem:

The problem is that on first attempt to re-login, user is redirected to the logout method, which then returns them to the login screen(verified this in network tab of browser)

Question:

How do I make laravel forget this URL and process like new login, or is there a better way to be handling this logout?

Here is my code:

routes.php file:

```
$router->get('auth/logout', 'AdminAuthController@logout');
```

AdminAuthController:

```
namespace App\Admin\Controllers;

use Encore\Admin\Controllers\AuthController;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AdminAuthController extends AuthController
{
use AuthenticatesUsers {
    logout as logoutUser;
}

 public function logout(Request $request) {
    //runs the Encore/Admin logout function
    parent::getLogout();

    //runs standard logout to logout user after admin logout
    $this->logoutUser($request);

    //redirect to home whcih will be login page since user is logged out
    return redirect('/');
 }
}
```

Parent Function:

```
/**
 * User logout.
 *
 * @return Redirect
 */
public function getLogout()
{
    Auth::guard('admin')->logout();

    session()->forget('url.intented');

    return redirect(config('admin.prefix'));
}
```

Comment: Did you try removing intended url when logging out ? `Session::forget('url.intended');`

Comment: I did. it's in the parent function, I'll add that code now to be more explicit. Thanks.

Comment: You have a typo in "intented" (3rd line of getLogout()). It should say: 


```session()->forget('url.intended');```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

I recognize this might not be the most optimal solution, but it will work and it generally makes logical sense.

In my authenticated method (so post login) I check the intended URL string, if it contains the word logout, I redirect to the root page of the application.. because logically on login, you should never be accessing logout.

```
if(str_contains(redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath())->getTargetUrl(), 'logout')){
        return redirect('/');
    }
return redirect()->intended($this->redirectPath());
```

I'm still open to improvements so if anyone has better ideas, please post them!